# Almost duplicated unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, duplicates, refactoring

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
    public string ValueDescription 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return Value > 10 ? "Value bigger than 10" : default(string); 
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach to test the `ValueDescription` logic?
I only see two ways of testing it. One way would be using expected result as a parameter:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestTest
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase(12, false)]
    [TestCase(10, false)]
    [TestCase(9, true)]
    [TestCase(1, true)]
    public void Should_ReturnValueDescription_AccordingToValue(int? value, bool isNullResult)
    {
        var mockTest = new Test(value);

        Assert.AreEqual(string.IsNullOrEmpty(mockTest.ValueDescription), isNullResult);
    }
}
```

And the other way would be "duplicating" part of the test code (can't see it quite explicit here, because it's quite a simple example), and just changing the `Assert` method.

```
[Test]
[TestCase(12)]
[TestCase(50)]
[TestCase(100)]
[TestCase(300)]
public void Should_ReturnValueDescription_When_ValueBiggerThan10(int? value, bool isNullResult)
{
    var mockTest = new Test(value);

    Assert.IsNotNull(mockTest.ValueDescription);
}

[Test]
[TestCase(9)]
[TestCase(2)]
[TestCase(5)]
[TestCase(10)]
public void Should_ReturnValueDescription_When_ValueLowerOrEqualThan10(int? value, bool isNullResult)
{
    var mockTest = new Test(value);

    Assert.IsNull(mockTest.ValueDescription);
}
```

Considering that this is a quite simplistic example, what would be the best approach in this scenario and in a more complex scenario? (with the need of stubs and etc to test it)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would make sense to test if ValueDescription is equal to the expected string, in case of values > 10

```
[Test]
[TestCase(12)]
[TestCase(100)]
[TestCase(Int32.MaxValue)]
public void GivenATestWithValueBiggerThan10_ThenValueDescriptionShouldBeEqualsAsExpected(int value)
{
    // arrange
    var mockTest = new Test(value);

    // act/assert
    Assert.That(mockTest.ValueDescription, Is.EqualTo("Value bigger than 10"));
}
```

And check if ValueDescription is null, in case of values <= 10

```
[Test]
[TestCase(10)]
[TestCase(-100)]
[TestCase(Int32.MinValue)]
public void GivenATestWithValueLessOrEqualThan10_ThenValueDescriptionShouldBeNull(int value)
{
    // arrange
    var mockTest = new Test(value);

    // act/assert
    Assert.That(mockTest.ValueDescription, Is.Null);
}
```